# Как навести курсор мыши на первую букву найденного слова?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

**Получился вот такой код но он не работает, можете помочь?**

````
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui as pag

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://resh.edu.ru/subject/lesson/3352/train/#193834")

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'безопасность')]")
assert "безопасность" in driver.page_source

pag.moveTo(elem.location['x'], elem.location['y'] + elem.size['height']/2)```
````

Comment: Зачем вы используете устаревший код, да еще и с ошибками? Зачем ищете текст которого нет на этой странице?? И делаете бессмысленное действие по наведению мыши???

Comment: Я делаю программу которая сама будет выполнять задание, при совпадения ответа он будет выбирать его

Answer (score -1):

код выглядит почти правильно, но забыл добавить клик мышью. Вот исправленный код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui as pag

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://resh.edu.ru/subject/lesson/3352/train/#193834")

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'safety')]")
assert "safety" in driver.page_source

pag.moveTo(elem.location['x'], elem.location['y'] + elem.size['height']/2)
pag.click()  # Добавляем клик по найденному элементу
```

Comment: Пробовали запустить свой код?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    pag.moveTo(elem.location['x'], elem.location['y'] + elem.size['height']/2)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location'